# Completeness of infinitely intersecting geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a connected, smooth, strongly causal Lorentzian manifold, and consider an inextendible causal geodesic $\sigma : [0,b) \to M$ (a priori, $b$ may be $\infty$) with the following property:

For every sequence $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset [0,b)$ such that $s_n \to b$, there exists a subsequence $(s_{n_k})$ and an inextendible, **incomplete** geodesic $\gamma:[0,1) \to M$ such that there's a sequence $(t_k) \subset [0,1)$ with $t_k \to 1$ and $\sigma(s_{n_k}) = \gamma(t_k)$. In words: given any sequence whatsoever along the end of $\sigma$, there's an incomplete geodesic that intersects $\sigma$ infinitely many times along some subsequence.

**Question:** Must $\sigma$ be incomplete, i.e. must $b$ be finite?

**Notes**:

Of course, if $\sigma$ is incomplete, the property is satisfied trivially by taking $\gamma$ to be the appropriate reparameterization of $\sigma$.

*Inextendible* here means that $\displaystyle \lim_{s \to b} \sigma(s)$ does not exist (and similarly for $\gamma$), so that $\sigma$ cannot be future-extended as continuous curve (or, equivalently, as a smooth geodesic).

While I'm not sure if the causality and inextendibility conditions are necessary for the result, together they imply that $\sigma(s_n)$ can never converge, and hence that the image of $\sigma$ is closed, and further that $\sigma$ eventually exits and remains outside of any compact set.

My intuition is that the answer is positive, but I'm not sure how to go about a proof-- it seems one would want to somehow bound the parameter of $\sigma$ in terms of that of some $\gamma$.

If absolutely necessary, I'd also be interested in a positive answer under the additional hypothesis that the $\gamma$ are causal.

**Edit:** Since no answers have been given after a bit of time, I've now [cross-posted this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408277/completeness-of-infinitely-intersecting-causal-geodesics-in-strongly-causal-spac) on MathOverflow.

Comment: Not an answer, but a half-baked idea: for time-like $\gamma$, I think, it should be possible to argue via Lorentzian distances, if you assume all geodesics are parametrized by arc-length: the Lorentzian distance between the $\gamma(t_k)$ gets arbitrarily small, as $(t_k)$ converges. As $\sigma(s_{n_k})=\gamma(t_k)$ this should give a contradiction if $s_n\to\infty$. Maybe this can be extended to causal $\gamma$. I suspect that this does not hold for space-like $\gamma$, as time-like and space-like completeness are notoriously independent. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @AlexD If you can see how to formalize this argument even for specifically timelike $\gamma$ and/or $\sigma$, I would accept it as the answer (unless/until someone can argue a more general case). I had similar thoughts, i.e. somehow using the heuristic that $\gamma$ should be a local maximum of the proper time functional between subsequent intersections, but I can't see how to make such a comparison between $\gamma$ and $\sigma$ precise.